# Extracting multiple sheets and specific data from two sheets ("Input" and "AttributeInfo")

Tags: vba, excel

I get a runtime '1004'' Error 'Copy' of object '_worksheet' failed when I run this code. The highlighted line is

`ws.copy` right below the `for loop`.

I am seeking to extract specific data from two specific sheets while all data from every sheet.  I am able to get the all data from every sheet but the other portion is giving me an error.

```
Sub outfor2()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next ws


Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B12").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSPQRE.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close


Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B13").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSfinalQRE.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B14").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSerrs.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B15").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSplural.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B16").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NumStrat.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B17").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "tossStratumNum.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B18").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "UsedEstimator.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B19").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "notUsedEstimator.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B20").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "RelPrecision.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B21").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "tossedPQREs.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B22").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "tossedPQREpercent.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B23").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "PointEstimate.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B24").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "LowerConfBound.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B25").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QREest.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Wyear.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B8").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "PSAM.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B7").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "apportionment.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B9").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "deviations.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "year.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B26").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "yearCOMMA.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "clientLATEX.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close


Sheets("AttributeInfo").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "AttFsize.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close


Sheets("AttributeInfo").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "AttSsize.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets("AttributeInfo").Select
Range("B7").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Atterror.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close



Sheets("AttributeInfo").Select
Range("B8").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ATTPSAM.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close


Sheets("AttributeInfo").Select
Range("B9").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ATTdeviations.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close






Dim file As String
file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "PSAM.txt"

Dim lines As Collection
Set lines = New Collection

Dim s As String

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1

Dim i As Integer
Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "deviations.txt"

Set lines = New Collection


Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1


file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "yearCOMMA.txt"

Set lines = New Collection


Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1







file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "LowerConfBound.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "LowerConfBound.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1


file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "PointEstimate.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "PointEstimate.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QREest.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QREest.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QREest.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QREest.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "tossedPQREs.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "tossedPQREs.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSfinalQRE.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSfinalQRE.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1


file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSPQRE.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CSPQRE.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1







file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "apportionment.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1


file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ATTPSAM.txt"

Set lines = New Collection


Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1


Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ATTdeviations.txt"

Set lines = New Collection


Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1



file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "AttSsize.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "AttSsize.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, " """, "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1


file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "AttFsize.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """ ", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1








file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "clientLATEX.txt"

Set lines = New Collection

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, """", "")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

Open file For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, s
lines.Add Replace(s, "&", "\&")
Loop
Close #1

Open file For Output As #1
For i = 1 To lines.Count
Print #1, lines(i)
Next i
Close #1

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Uh given the countless `select`s you have, guess you missed one before the copy XD

Comment: flipping between opening, closing, and active workbooks gets confusing.  Take the time to fully qualify your references and you should be able to find your error pretty quick.

Comment: Wait, does your code die on line 10 (right after the for loop)? Because you just closed the active book so how can it pick up sheet "input"? Not to mention that ws.copy inside the loop is pointless XD

Comment: You don't need to `select` so much. You can use `Sheets("Input").Range("B3").copy`. When you debug, what line is highlighted?

Comment: The "ws.Copy" line under "For Each ws In Worksheets"

Comment: lol set the worksheet as @sous2817 suggested. Edit: that loop is bonkers actually XD